# MySQL: Log Summary Query

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a module in my CMS system that allows the web site to display Advertisements. It logs views and clicks.  The query I use to summarize the log is performing poorly.

This is the query:

```
SELECT `a`.`id`,
    `a`.`active`,
    `a`.`static`,
    `a`.`position`,
    `a`.`file`,
    `a`.`title`,
    `a`.`url`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `lv`.`id`) AS `views`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `lc`.`id`) AS `clicks` 
FROM `ads` AS `a` 
LEFT JOIN `ad_log` AS `lv` 
    ON `lv`.`ad_id` = `a`.`id` 
    AND `lv`.`type` = 'view' 
    AND `lv`.`created` BETWEEN '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
        AND '2011-12-31 23:59:59' 
LEFT JOIN `ad_log` AS `lc` 
    ON `lc`.`ad_id` = `a`.`id` 
    AND `lc`.`type` = 'click' 
    AND `lc`.`created` BETWEEN '2011-01-01 00:00:00' 
        AND '2011-12-31 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY `a`.`id` 
ORDER BY `a`.`static` DESC,
    `a`.`position` ASC,
    `a`.`title` ASC
```

The `ad_log` table has a two-column index on the `ad_id` and `type` columns.  When I look at the profiler results, it is using that index.  Would a different index be more performant?

---

**UPDATE**

After testing different index combinations, it seems that the current one is best. Maybe there's a better way to write the query?

Here's a screen capture of `EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`:

[image: EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...]

---

**SOLUTION**

I have accepted [DRapp's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8491648/244826), but here is the query that I'd come up with.  It's only slightly less performant than [DRapp's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8491648/244826):

```
SELECT `a`.`id`,
    `a`.`active`,
    `a`.`static`,
    `a`.`position`,
    `a`.`file`,
    `a`.`title`,
    `a`.`url`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM `ad_log` 
        WHERE `ad_id` = `a`.`id` 
        AND `type` = 'view' 
        AND `created` BETWEEN '2011-11-01 00:00:00' 
            AND '2011-11-30 23:59:59') AS `views`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM `ad_log`
        WHERE `ad_id` = `a`.`id`
        AND `type` = 'click'
        AND `created` BETWEEN '2011-11-01 00:00:00'
            AND '2011-11-30 23:59:59') AS `clicks` 
FROM `ads` AS `a` 
ORDER BY `a`.`static` DESC,
    `a`.`position` ASC,
    `a`.`title` ASC
```

---

**BEST PERFORMANCE**

This query, inspired by [DRapp's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8491648/244826), has even better performance:

```
SELECT `a`.`id`,
    `a`.`active`,
    `a`.`static`,
    `a`.`position`,
    `a`.`file`,
    `a`.`title`,
    `a`.`url`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `l`.`type` = 'view' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `views`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `l`.`type` = 'click' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `clicks` 
FROM `ads` AS `a` 
LEFT JOIN `ad_log` AS `l`
    ON `a`.`id` = `l`.`ad_id`
    AND `l`.`created` BETWEEN '2011-11-01 00:00:00'
        AND '2011-11-30 23:59:59'
GROUP BY `a`.`id`
ORDER BY `a`.`static` DESC,
    `a`.`position` ASC,
    `a`.`title` ASC
```

Comment: Out of interest could you also post the output of EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ..... rest of your query

Comment: Post the output of the explain query.

Comment: @AdrianCornish and @daking963 - I have posted a screenshot of the `EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE` results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach might be to have sub-select as the joins that pre-aggregates all view/clicks by the date range ONCE, then joins to all ads that were available.

```
SELECT 
      a.id,
      a.active,
      a.static,
      a.position,
      a.file,
      a.title,
      a.url,
      COALESCE( PreAgg.CntViews, 0 ) views,
      COALESCE( PreAgg.CntClicks, 0 ) clicks
   FROM
      ads AS a 
      LEFT JOIN 
         ( select lv.ad_id,
                  sum( if( lv.type = 'view', 1, 0 )) as CntViews,
                  sum( if( lv.type = 'click', 1, 0 )) as CntClicks
              from
                 ad_log lv
              where
                     lv.type in ( 'view', 'click' )
                 and lv.created between '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
                                    AND '2011-12-31 23:59:59' 
              group by
                  lv.ad_id ) PreAgg
        on A.ID = PreAgg.Ad_ID
```

It might be even faster if you have an index on the Ad_Log table based on (type, created, ad_id )... This way, for each "Type" will be grouped, then within each type, jump right to the date-range.  So it should only have to hit 2 sections of the index... "view" by from/to and "click" by from/to.  Instead of each "ad id", then check the types, then the dates...

Comment: I was working on a solution with sub-selects for each count column, but I like the pre-aggregation idea. My sub-select solution is much faster than my posted query, but this seems faster yet.

Comment: @Sonny, yet another possibility to optimize inner query by its index.  See comment

Comment: I tried adding different indexes, but it continues to use the foreign key index for the pre-aggregation section.

Answer (score 2):

You can index `ad_id, type, and created` to get faster results.

[This](http://hackmysql.com/case4) is a good read on how to index for joins. Read the other cases too, they are helpful.

You can further optimize it by indexing the [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html) columns but remember with more indexes your writes will be slower.

Comment: After further testing, adding `created` to the index slowed the query even more.